# PHP function to receive AJAX variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, variables

Im trying to send AJAX variable:rowID to my php file but i keep getting

> Notice: Undefined index: phpID

I am completely new to PHP and AJAX , please help.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var log = jQuery("#log");

jQuery(".getRow").click(function() {
console.log("Clicked a row...");
var rowID = jQuery(this).find("td.idCell").text();

//Print the row ID in the log cell to make sure we got the right one.
log.text("You 1clicked row "+rowID);
console.log("You cl2icked row "+rowID);

//Send the row ID to ajaxupdate.php
//jQuery.post("/abac/ajaxupdate.php", { what: "updateRow", PHP_ID: "rowID"})
jQuery.post("/abac/ajaxupdate.php", {phpID: "rowID"})
.done( function(data) {

var results = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
console.log(rowID);
})
.fail( function() {
console.log("AJAX POST failed.");
});
});

});

</script>
```

I was under the impression isset($_POST['rowID'])) passes rowID from my ajax into a $_POST but its not working ?

```
<?php 

     if( (isset($_POST['submit'])) || isset($_POST['phpID'])))
     {     
        $rowID = $_POST['rowID'];
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();

        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query
        ->select($db->quoteName(array('CV_ID', 'Classifier', 'Value', 'TP_ID')))
        ->from($db->quoteName('sessionta'))
        ->where($db->quoteName('TP_ID') . ' LIKE '. $db->quote('$phpID'));

        $db->setQuery($query);
        $results = $db->loadObjectList();

    }
?>
```

Just in case here is the table that is being clicked, have i got the Form right?:

```
<form name="Permit" id="Permit" action="<?php echo JURI::current(); ?>" method="post">
<p style="width: 46px; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 207px"><input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="save" /></p>
<table border="",th,td, width="500", align="center">
<tr>
<th>TP ID</th>
<th>Permit Deny</th>
<th>Level</th>
<th>Session</th>
<th>Information Specialist</th>
</tr>

<?php foreach ($results as $row): ?>

<tr class="getRow">
<td id="ID_ID" name="ID_ID" class="idCell"><?php echo $row->TP_ID ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->Permit_or_Deny ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->Level ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->Session ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->Information_specialist ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: see you hav an error here jQuery.post("/abac/ajaxupdate.php", {phpID: "rowID"}) it should be jQuery.post("/abac/ajaxupdate.php", {phpID: rowID})  without quotes

Comment: you haven't inputs named 'phpID' and 'rowID'.add inputs to your view.

Comment: @CodingAnt Still getting it ? thanks for the reply, Is there something wrong with my php? is there a way to check phpID is really getting the rowID?

Comment: @IshaS sorry i dont quite understand?

Comment: Oh and just incase it helps AJAX is passing a number? does this affect any thing

Comment: @user3425742 your form haven't a input field named 'phpID' or 'rowID'.how can you get the post values? so add the input fields and named them as 'phpID' and 'rowID'.your form has only <tr> and <td> s not <input> fields.

Comment: what your console network tab says when you make an ajax request ?

Comment: @ishaS he is passing in Ajax post request , please check it

Comment: @CodingAnt its post says 

Clicked a row... edit-tp:164
You cl2icked row 989 edit-tp:169
989

Comment: no dude , I meant "network" panel , where you can see XHR request

Comment: @CodingAnt Not to sure what you mean? This is my first doing all of this

Answer (score 0):

```
     function ajax_post()
                                        {


                                            $.ajax({
                                                url: 'backend.php',
                                                dataType: 'json',
                                                type: 'GET',
                                                timeout: 30 * 1000,
                                                data: {key: value, key1: value1},
                                                success: function(json) {

                                                   alert('success');

                                                },
                                                error: function() {
                                                alert('failed');
                                                }

                                            });
```

use this as onclick event. and request in backend as following

```
 $keyvalue= $_REQUEST['key'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code. I think it will be helpful for you and you will understand

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.getRow').click(function(){
//Just to check whether click function is working
alert('Hiiii');

var rowID = $('td.idCell').text();

//Just to check whether rowID is getting assigned
alert(rowID);

$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'abac/ajaxupdate.php',
            data: 'phpID='+rowID,
            success:function(data, status)
            {
                alert(data);
                //Do success action here...
            }
        });
});
</script>
<form name="Permit" id="Permit" action="<?php echo JURI::current(); ?>" method="post">
  <p style="width: 46px; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 207px">
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="save" />
  </p>
  <table border="",th,td, width="500", align="center">
    <tr>
      <th>TP ID</th>
      <th>Permit Deny</th>
      <th>Level</th>
      <th>Session</th>
      <th>Information Specialist</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($results as $row): ?>
    <tr class="getRow">
      <td id="ID_ID" name="ID_ID" class="idCell"><?php echo $row->TP_ID; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row->Permit_or_Deny; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row->Level; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row->Session; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row->Information_specialist; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </table>
</form>
```

And place the following code in abac/ajaxupdate.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if((isset($_POST['submit'])) || isset($_POST['phpID']))
{     
    echo $rowID = $_POST['phpID'];
    exit;
    //Do Php actions here...
}
?>
```

So that you will get the alert with the TP_ID when data processed successful. If not so you have to check your PHP code.

Comment: Thanks you, but unfortunately i still get 

 Undefined index: phpID in C:\xampp\htdocs\abac\ajaxupdate.php

Could you help me understand something, in the php file which one am i trying to retreive int the $_POST phpID or rowID??
data: {'phpID' :rowID},

Comment: I edited my answer, There i added some more alerts to check each and every step is working or not. Using the alert values you can identify where the problem occurs. And please open your Firebug console panel and verify the ajax post datas. Firebug will be more helpful for finding this kind of errors.